Manage VLANs on Linux Bridge and KVM host
I am here to ask for help about integrating VLAN, Linux bridges and KVM.
So, let me start with the setup I am trying to put in place. I have a network switch with a couple of links to a KVM server. On those link I am sending different VLANs tag (from 10 to 20). On the KVM server, I have configured a bond (bond1). Attached to the bond1 there is a bridge, let's call it data-bridge. I have a couple of VMs running on KVM. I want to attach one eth of VM1 to the bridge and receive only some VLAN tags, like 10-11-12-13 and then attach the eth of VM2 and receive only other tags, 13-14-15-16.
I want to get this:
Switch - TAG 10-20 -> KVM-bond1 -> ALL-TAG -> data-bridge -> TAG 10-13 -> VM1-eth1
Switch - TAG 10-20 -> KVM-bond1 -> ALL-TAG -> data-bridge -> TAG 13-16 -> VM2-eth1
How that would be possible to do?
More info:

I have read that KVM integrates well with OVS and that would be easy to handle. But I don't want to install OVS. Or at least, I want to try to solve it with standard bridges.

I don't want to do the trick by creating interface.VLAN and then attach a bridge to it, something like this: bond1 -> data-bridge -> interface.VLAN11 -> bridge-vlan11 -> VM1-eth11. Also, that would do the work but I have to do this for every VLAN, which is not scalable for high number of VLANs and VMs.

I could attach directly eth of VMs to the data-bridge and then manage tags on the VMs, by creating eth1.11, eth1.12, eth1.13, ... on the VM. That would work as well, even if that means that VMs will receive traffic from all the VLANs, and VMs could configure interface on VLANs where they are not supposed to have an interface.

I am using networkd files to configure all this setup. From what I have done so far, creation of the bond and the bridge is fine. I have tried with some veth and namespaces on a test machine and this was working, I cannot figure out how to do this with KVM VMs.


In a test machine I was playing with namespace and veth, making a file in /etc/systemd/network/1-test_veth.network:
[Match]
Name=test_veth
[Network]
Bridge=br0
[BridgeVLAN]
VLAN=10-12
PVID=10
EgressUntagged=10

This works like a charm with veth and namespace. It seems like I cannot do the same with KVM, so I assume I must declare VLANs on the XML of the VM. But seems like VLAN are manageable from KVM only if OVS, SR-IOV or hostdev are used as interface device.
I could try commands like bridge vlan add dev vm1-interface vid 10 untagged maybe, but that wouldn't be perpetual. Maybe hookup scripts could be a solution?
Do you have any hint or there is no hope for this?

libvirt (which you seem to be using, based on the link in the post) doesn't support normal Linux VLAN-aware bridges (in the sense, it doesn't know how to manage filters, a.k.a. configuring tagging). Yes, you may do it by hand, but it won't be perpetual. If you want to have a KVM server that supports this natively in an convenient way, consider using Proxmox VE.

yes, I am using libvirt. Proxmox VE is not an alternative, sadly. Thank you for the feedback!

libvirt will support this if you are using openvswitch bridges instead of standard legacy bridges. See e.g. here.

yep, I know OVS would do the trick, but my aim was to find a way with standard bridges.

Avoiding the additional bridges is possible when utilizing MacVTap:
Switch - tagged port -> Linux physical interfaces -> Linux bond interface -> Linux VLAN interfaces -> Linux MacVTap interfaces for VMs

In the host networking system (such as systemd-networkd), the following are configured:

Physical interfaces (for example eth0 and eth1)
Bond (for example bond0)
VLAN interfaces (for example vlan10)

In the Libvirt domain definition of a VM, the network interface is configured as direct:
<interface type='direct' trustGuestRxFilters='yes'>
  <mac address='xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx'/>
  <source dev='vlan10' mode='bridge'/>
  <target dev='vm1'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
</interface>

With this example, Libvirt will create and manage the vm1@vlan10 MacVTap interface on the host when the VM is running.
The resulting interface can be inspected using ip -d l sh vm1 to validate it is configured with implied bridge and macvtap.

Hello, thank you for the feedback! That is a way to manage VLAN, but I need to create an interface for any new VLAN, which is something i want to avoid. That would be hard to manage if we have a lot of VMs with a lot of VLANs. I want to get a specific set of VLAN on a single VM interface.

After a lot of attempts, seems like linux bridges can't do what i want with KVM. The only "solution" I have found is the following:
bond1 -> bridge data ( vlan-filtering1 ) -> veth (vlan 10-13 ) -> bridge-vlan10-13 ( vlan-filtering0 )-> VM-interface.
In this way I am able to segregate some VLANs and send only some of them to a VM host. Is not the best solution, but is the best I was able to find with linux bridge.
OVS would do the trick, I know :)

You can use standard bridges with KVM, I do it all the time. It's libvirt is what you can't use them with. KVM is not synonymous with libvirt; as I stated already, Proxmox VE uses KVM like libvirt does (because it runs Qemu as a VM monitor too, same as libvirt does), and it can use standard bridges with VLAN filters.

Yes, would have been better to say that I can't do what i want with libvirt. I will totally keep in mind to give a try to Proxmox, thank you for the hint.
